# Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In my Java code, I have an `ArrayList` of `String`s. I'd like to put this data in a JavaScript variable on a JSP page I'm working on. My first thought was to include it directly, e.g.:

```
var myArray = <%= arrayList %>;
```

Unfortunately, when executed, `myArray` is a string in the format `[a,b,c]`, not an actual JavaScript array. How do I get some data from a Java `ArrayList` to a JavaScript array?

Comment: please add more code with an example data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `<%=arraylist%>` it calls the `toString()` on list and prints  `[a,b,c]`

And No,you cannot direclty convert From Java `arrayList` to javascript array ,Convert the Java `ArrayList` to `JSON String`, and use `JSON.parse()` to get Javascript `object`.

Have a look at [*Json objet*](http://www.json.org/)  and [*Json in java*](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have the json string like [a,b,c]. When i use Json.parse(aa); It shows the error. Uncaught reference error.a is not defined. So it must be like ["a","b","c"]. So how to convert like this?

Comment: Dude,you have to add json library to your class path and convert your arraylist on serverside to json string and send it to client.Then JSON.parse() works :)

Comment: The second link in the answer is not available anymore.

Answer (score 13):

Withoug a library:

Java:

```
public static String toJavascriptArray(String[] arr){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("[");
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        sb.append("\"").append(arr[i]).append("\"");
        if(i+1 < arr.length){
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

JSP:

```
var myArray = <%= toJavascriptArray(arrayList) %>;
```

Comment: Technique is good, but still you need to parse it to JSON, while assigning to javascript variable.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in your JSP page

```
<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("one");
strList.add("two");
strList.add("three"); %>

var jsArray = [<% for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) { %>"<%= strList.get(i) %>"<%= i + 1 < strList.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];
```

The output will be

```
var jsArray = ["one","two","three"];
```

If your List was empty it will output

```
var jsArray = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript split() method returns an array, so it's a simple way to convert a Java ArrayList into a JavaScript array.

```
function toJavascript(){
    var array="<%=javaArrayList%>";
    array=array.replace("[", "");
    array=array.replace("]", "");
    return javaArray.split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
var myArray = <%=net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(arrayList) %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
 var jsArray = JSON.parse(yourJavaListObject)
```