# How to access the java List of a custom class objects specified in <s:iterator> tag of jsp file inside my javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, iterator

I have jsp file in which i am getting a List of objects from my java action class (struts2) and displaying it.Now i want to access these list objects inside my javascript method.How to do this?

mycode.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Some functions
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-form").trigger('click');
        //Problem is how to access myObjectsList here 
        //and which is of type MyCustom class with 2 class variables(i.e., name and id)
        //I need to access name and id as well

          var colFamilies ='${myObjectsList}';
          alert(myObjectsList);
    });
//Some functions
</script>

<html>
<!-- my code -->
<s:iterator value="myObjectsList" var="myObject">
<li><h4>
<s:property value="#myObject.name" />
</a>
</h4></li>
<!-- my code -->
</html>
```

Please give me some suggestions 
I am tired of goggling since 2 days

Comment: Are you sure its not working? Did you try to print it using <c:out> tag?

Comment: As I know <c:out > can only be used in JSP/HTML, but I want to access the class objects inside the javascript code. I am new to JavaScript. Could you explain your suggestion in detail ?

Comment: I'm just saying that are you sure that variable contains some value? List out those value on jsp using JSTL to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are attempting to assign a list of some non-primitive type as a JavaScript array.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17440755/2782261) answer may be helpful to you. In short, you may need to do some converting rather than directly assigning this object. Since the linked answer uses a static utility method, you may need to consider doing the conversion on your backend.