# Can not highlight dates from Mysql in jquery datepicker calendar in jsp

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

I am trying to display jquery datepicker calendar with highlights dates witch stored in mysql.
the problem is when run the script with custom dates, its display calendar with highlights dates.below code is running with custom dates,

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {

    var custom_dates = ["2014-10-31","2014-10-28","2014-10-27","2014-10-03","2014-10-29","2014-11-04"];

        var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

       for (i = 0; i < custom_dates.length; i++) {

            if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,custom_dates) != -1) {

                return [true, 'css-for-DBdates', 'Planned date'];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
```

But when I run the script with dates from database, its display calendar without highlights dates. below code is running with database dates,

**index.jsp**

```
<%
    ArrayList Datesinarray=new ArrayList();

    try
    {
    String class1=session.getAttribute("class").toString();
    String userid=session.getAttribute("user_id").toString();
    String subject=session.getAttribute("subject").toString();
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raptor1_5","root","");
    Statement st=connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select date from tblplanner where User_id='"+userid+"' and class='"+class1+"' and subject='"+subject+"'");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        char a='"';
        String c="'";

        String datefrdb = rs.getString("date");
        String bb=a+datefrdb+a;
        Datesinarray.add(bb);
        //System.out.println();
    }
System.out.println("array value is :"+Datesinarray);

%>

<script>

 $( "#datetextbox").datepicker({ 

beforeShowDay: function(date) {

           var DB_dates = [<%=Datesinarray%>];

            var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

            for (i = 0; i < DB_dates.length; i++) {

                if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,DB_dates) != -1) {

                     return [true, 'css-for-DBdates', 'Planned date'];
                         }
                   }
                       return [true];
                    }
});

</script>
```

the dates from DB printing like **array value is :["2014-10-27", "2014-10-28", "2014-10-29", "2014-10-30", "2014-10-31", "2014-11-03"]**.

someone tell me where I am wrong?

**Note:** when I print custom_dates.length,its shows 6. but DB_dates.length shows 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did small mistake in the script that i initialized the variable values **var DB_dates = [<%=Datesinarray%>]**; instead of **var DB_dates = <%=Datesinarray%>;**.

Its working fine now.