# Convert a JavaScript string array into a Java string array

Tags: java, javascript

I'm using Apache Tomcat for my study project and I want to convert a JavaScript array into a Java array. Is that possible? I saw some questions before but that didn't really answer my question.

If there's a way to do that, would you like to give a little explanation?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array

Comment: @user3634133 Have a code? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I dont have a code yet, I tried some stuff but none worked. I have actually not a specific idea of how to program it with JSP, Java (servlets). @PaulVargas

Comment: @user3634133 There are many videos on youtube that can help. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=JSP