# Use javascript variable in el expression in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is the situation,I want to iterate through an ArrayList(of JSP) using a javascript variable.The code would be somewhat like follows-

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
alert('<%=allViewIds.get(i)%>');    
}
```

But I am not able to use i variable inside that jsp scriptlet.Can anyone please tell me as to how can I achieve this task?

Thanks In advance

Comment: Might want to take a look at [Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the `for` loop inside your jsp scriptlets rather than doing it javascript, like:

```
<%
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { %>
    alert('<%= allViewIds.get(i) %>');<%
}
%>
```

`i` in your code exists in javascript land. But you're trying to use it within jsp scriptlet tags.

Comment: I am calling that javascript code on an specific event.How will I be able to call JSP code on occurance of an event

Comment: Without knowing the context of your project it's hard to advise. The way jsp works is it generates HTML code on your server to gives to the client. If you're looking to trigger a process on an event it's best to just use javascript and not bother with jsp. But like I said without knowing what you're trying to achieve it's hard to recommend what to do.