# Arraylist<String> to javascript array in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, collections

I am having an `ArrayList<String> reportNames` which i am sending as `request.setAttribute("reportNames", reportNames);`

How to assign **ArrayList** values to my **javascript** array on Jsp.

```
 var MyReports = [<%reportNames%>];
```

Comment: You have to convert your array list to JSON

Comment: I could find a similar problem in the below link. Hope it helps you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 2):

You could do this like bellow using JSP **c:forEach** and Javascript **push()**.

**Sample Code:**

```
var MyReports  = [];
<c:forEach var="reportName" items="${reportNames}">
  MyReports.push(${reportName});
</c:forEach>
```