# Java ArrayList to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Having spent a week trying to get a java ArrayList to 'appear'in javascript (in the same jsp) I am at the point of giving up as
none of the supposed 'examples' in various forums works.

As a last resort I attempted this with JSON, but that doesn't work either.

If this is an impossibility then can someone confirm that?

There is a SQL select followed by a c:set (in JSTL) followed by a java ArrayList (in a java scriplet in the same jsp) inside a c:forEach loop.

This is working properly and the output is   1  6  3  2  1  7 etc

There is also a StringBuffer which adds commas,

this is also working properly and the output is 1,6,3,2,7 etc.

I now want that same array, in the same format, to appear in javascript
(in the same jsp) so I can use it for dynamic arrays in chart.js.

Hence my 'final' attempt' to use JSON.

It doesn't matter whether the JSON is after the ArrayList or after the StringBuffer as long as I can get the array into javascript.

However the JSON code produces what appears to be each element of the array in its own square brackets (jsonQuantities = [1]  jsonQuantities=[6] etc

```
<c:set var="quantity" value="${row.Quantity}"  />
<c:set var="zone" value="${row.zone}" />

<%
//produce array

ArrayList quantities= new ArrayList();
quantities.add(pageContext.getAttribute("quantity"));

//convert to JSON

Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonQuantities = gson.toJson(quantities);
out.println("jsonQuantities = " + jsonQuantities);

//add commas

StringBuffer thesequantities = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i<quantities.size(); i++)
{
thesequantities.append(quantities.get(i));
thesequantities.append(",");
}

out.println(thesequantities.toString());

%>     
</c:forEach>
```

Then I attempt to get the array into javascript - the JSON.parse line does nothing other than prevent any JavaScript below it from executing.
I have tried various forEach loops and so called 'conversions' to output the array
but nothing works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myobject = JSON.parse("jsonQuantities");
document.write("the quantities are" +myobject.count);
```

All the examples using c:forEach (i.e. below), getParameter, getAttribute etc do not work.

```
var jsArray = [ 
<c:forEach var="item" items="${jsonQuantities}">
<c:out value="${item}"/>,
 </c:forEach>
];
```

Does anybody have actual working code / experience of this (without using separate php, jsp's etc)?

All I need is the java ArrayList (1  6  3  2  1  7 etc) or StringBuffer (1,6,3,2,7 etc) contents 'transferred' to javascript and then output (so I can see all the elements
irrespective of what they are named or in which format they are in).

Thanks, Ralph

Comment: Did you try the code in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array

Comment: It's strange your code above (in the scriptlet) works since you just add one element to the quantities ArrayList.  quantities.add(pageContext.getAttribute("quantity")); It's the only element added

Comment: Yes, but I cant use a 'return' because the ArrayList is created inside a forEach loop and return breaks that loop (and without the break all those examples result in 'jsonQuantities' cant be resolved'

Comment: As an aside the jsp auto-refreshes every 5 secs (for other functions) and so if I can find some way of saving the array after each pass then I can hopefully 'get' it in javascript.

Comment: Don't use raw types for your ArrayList please